# Check user's role and store in variable

Tags: plugin-development, user-roles

I am using **custom user roles** which I create and assign by using a plugin. I was wondering how I could retrieve the user's role and store it in a PHP variable.

What I am trying to achieve is something like this:

Let's say I created 3 custom user roles: `role_apple`, `role_banana` and `role_carrot`

```
if ( 'role_apple' === $user_role ) {
    echo 'User is an apple';
}
elseif ( 'role_banana' === $user_role ) {
    echo 'User is a bannana';
}
```

How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to store anything, just check the current logged in user via [`user_can`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/user_can):

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
if ( user_can( $current_user, "role_apple" ) ){
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Hey, I tried the code you gave me but it won't function...I tried it with two accounts, one with the role "Administrator" and one with the role "User" but it doesn't work for some reason.

I tried it like this


global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
if ( user_can( $current_user, "Administrator" ) ){
  echo "Admin";
}else{
 echo "other";
}

Comment: it's case-sensitive, try `administrator` all lower-case.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot :) Works perfect. Didn't know it was case sensetive.